# Change order of subplots

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to change the order of subplots in plotly for R? Is there a way to manually change the levels of a factor in this code?
I want a plot with Weight in the first plot followed by  a,b,c in order above it. But what I get as output is Weight, c, a and b as shown in the image graph

Here is my code

```
df<-data.frame("time"= seq(0.01,10,length.out=100),"Weight"=1:100, "a"=rnorm(100),"b"=rnorm(100),"c"=rnorm(100))

q <- df%>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -time) %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~time, y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
          yaxis = ~paste0("y", id)
          ) %>%

 layout(
  xaxis = list(title = "Time,s",tickfont = list(size = 17),titlefont = list(size = 20)),
  yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 17), title="DP"),
  hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=20))
) %>% 
  add_lines() %>%
  subplot(nrows = length(df)-1, shareX = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is re-ordering factor levels as below:

```
# set.seed to keep the exact same results 
set.seed(123) 
df<-data.frame("time"= seq(0.01,10,length.out=100),"Weight"=1:100, "a"=rnorm(100),"b"=rnorm(100),"c"=rnorm(100))

DF <- df%>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -time) %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable)))
DF$variable <- factor(DF$variable, levels = c("Weight", "a",  "b", "c")) #re-order 

q <- DF %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~time, y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
          yaxis = ~paste0("y", sort(id, decreasing =F))) %>% #sort the order
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Time,s",tickfont = list(size = 17),titlefont = list(size = 20)),
    yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 17), title="DP"),
    hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=20))
  ) %>% 
  add_lines() %>%
  subplot(nrows = length(df)-1, shareX = TRUE)

q
```

You will need `sort(id, decreasing =F)` to get exact same order of what you set in `factor(DF$variable, levels = c("Weight", "a",  "b", "c"))`.

[image]

Comment: Helllo thanks for the answer. The order of levels in your code is still different than the output ? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: You are not missing anything :) but I guess this was a second question. You need to set order and then sort it in your script. In the old version, I just modified the existing order so that it does the job for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might have been caused by `yaxis = ~paste0("y", id)`. I replaced it with `yaxis = ~paste0(id, "y")` to get the correct order. You may need to change some code to get the right format.

```
library(plotly)
df<-data.frame("time"= seq(0.01,10,length.out=100),"Weight"=1:100, "a"=rnorm(100),"b"=rnorm(100),"c"=rnorm(100))

q <- df%>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -time) %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~time, y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
          yaxis = ~paste0(id, "y")
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Time,s",tickfont = list(size = 17),titlefont = list(size = 20)),
    yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 17), title="DP"),
    hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=20))
  ) %>% 
  add_lines() %>%
  subplot(nrows = length(df), shareX = TRUE)
q
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the data, the name, and the line features of the top and bottom subplots as following code,

```
#assign q$x$data to one template variable p
p = q$x$data

#exchange the data, name, and line features of q$x$data[[1]] and q$x$data[[4]]
q$x$data[[1]]$x = p[[4]]$x
q$x$data[[1]]$y = p[[4]]$y
q$x$data[[1]]$name = p[[4]]$name
q$x$data[[1]]$line = p[[4]]$line

q$x$data[[4]]$x = p[[1]]$x
q$x$data[[4]]$y = p[[1]]$y
q$x$data[[4]]$name = p[[1]]$name
q$x$data[[4]]$line = p[[1]]$line

#show 
q
```

[image]